# DRF + DREST : how to ensure during tests, the serializer is compiled with the setUp test data?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, dynamic-rest

Using

- Django: 1.11
- Python 3.6
- DRF: 3.7
- DREST (aka dynamic rest): 1.8

I have a serializer written like this:

```
class SubProjectAsFKWithAttachedFieldsSerializer(DynamicModelSerializer):
    # attached_fields = AttachedFieldSerializer(embed=True, many=True)
    try:
        scope_object = UgField.objects.get(dotted_path='global.scope')
        scopes = DynamicRelationField(
            AttachedFieldWithDirectValuesSerializer,
            source='attached_fields',
            many=True,
            embed=True,
            read_only=True,
            queryset=AttachedField.objects.filter(ug_field=scope_object)
        )
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        scopes = DynamicRelationField(AttachedFieldWithDirectValuesSerializer,
                                      source='attached_fields',
                                      many=True,
                                      read_only=True,
                                      embed=True)
```

Currently, in almost all my `tests.py` in the setUp method, I have

```
self.global_scope_field = UgFieldFactory(dotted_path='global.scope', name='Scope')
```

For some reason, this line

```
scope_object = UgField.objects.get(dotted_path='global.scope')
```

keeps failing despite that I have "instantiated" using a `DjangoModelFactory`

What should I do to ensure that line always passes when I run tests?

**UPDATE**

1. Just to point out I actually have a UgField record which has the string `global.scope` as the value for the field `dotted_path`.
2. Only when I run `python manage.py test` do I face this issue.
3. When I run the app proper, there's no issue.

I have also tried setting

```
(self.global_scope_field, created) = UgField.objects.get_or_create(dotted_path='global.scope', name='Scope')
```

in my `setUp` method.

but then I get the same issue

[image]

Comment: erm I actually have a UgField record which has the string `global.scope` as the value for the field `dotted_path`. When I run the app proper, there's no issue. Only during tests do I face this issue

Comment: Maybe at the time of testing the record doesn't exist, but during runtime it already exists so you get a different serializer?  Perhaps initialize it at a different point in the test framework?  Using `try` in a class is just... sketchy, though clever.  I hope the reporting it does is accurate in that case, i've no experience.  Perhaps its actually throwin an exception on the code in the except: field

Answer (score 0):

For an object to be retrievable with `.get()` it has to be saved.

```
self.global_scope_field = UgFieldFactory(dotted_path='global.scope', name='Scope')
self.global_scope_field.is_valid()
self.global_scope_field.save()
```

Alternatively you could just create the object without a form.

```
self.global_scope_field = UgField.objects.create(dotted_path='global.scope', name='Scope')
```

Comment: Thanks for efforts. But the line is still skipped during django test. See updated question.